# cut() - include lowest values

Tags: r

I want to cut my data using defined breaks in `cut()`:

```
x = c(-10:10)

cut(x, c(-2,4,6,7))

[1] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   (-2,4] (-2,4] (-2,4] (-2,4] (-2,4] (-2,4] (4,6]  (4,6]  (6,7]  <NA>   <NA>  
[21] <NA>  
Levels: (-2,4] (4,6] (6,7]
```

However, I also want to obtain the levels `(minimum:-2]` and `(7:maximum]`. In the function `recode()` of the car-package one can use "lo:". Is there a similar thing available for cut?

Answer (score 9):

```
x <- -10:10

cut(x, c(-Inf, -2, 4, 6, 7, +Inf))

# Levels: (-Inf,-2] (-2,4] (4,6] (6,7] (7, Inf]
```

Comment: you don't need the `+` in front of the positive Inf

Comment: @ RJ: I know; it was only used for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `min()` and `max()` to evaluate the interval range (as Gavin mentioned) and set `include.lowest = TRUE` to make sure that the minimum value (here: -10) is part of the interval.

Input:

```
x = c(-10:10)

cut(x, c(min(x),-2,4,6,7,max(x)), include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
 [1] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] (-2,4]  
[11] (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (4,6]    (4,6]    (6,7]    (7,10]   (7,10]  
[21] (7,10]  
Levels: [-10,-2] (-2,4] (4,6] (6,7] (7,10]
```

Comment: `include.lowest` isn't doing anything here as you've already specified min & max (same result if you remove it). If you remove min() and try include.lowest true and false, you'll find the it either includes [ or doesn't include ( the lowest given breaks value, i.e. -2. Values below -2 are excluded regardless. Thanks for your answer because it led me to research and understand what include.lowest actually means!

Answer (score 6):

`findInterval` is the answer.

```
i <- findInterval(x, c(-2,4,6,7))

cbind(x, i)

        x i
 [1,] -10 0
 [2,]  -9 0
 [3,]  -8 0
 [4,]  -7 0
 [5,]  -6 0
 [6,]  -5 0
 [7,]  -4 0
 [8,]  -3 0
 [9,]  -2 1
[10,]  -1 1
[11,]   0 1
[12,]   1 1
[13,]   2 1
[14,]   3 1
[15,]   4 2
[16,]   5 2
[17,]   6 3
[18,]   7 4
[19,]   8 4
[20,]   9 4
[21,]  10 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I've run into trouble padding with `Inf` & `-Inf` before (though exactly why escapes me at this hour) so a safer solution might be to pad with the minimum and maximum values suitably extended:

```
x <- c(-10:10)
cut(x, c(min(x) -1 , -2, 4, 6, 7, max(x) + 1))

R> x <- c(-10:10)
R> cut(x, c(min(x) -1 , -2, 4, 6, 7, max(x) + 1))
 [1] (-11,-2] (-11,-2] (-11,-2] (-11,-2] (-11,-2] (-11,-2] (-11,-2] (-11,-2]
 [9] (-11,-2] (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (4,6]   
[17] (4,6]    (6,7]    (7,11]   (7,11]   (7,11]  
Levels: (-11,-2] (-2,4] (4,6] (6,7] (7,11]
```

In most cases though, Sven's Answer/solution will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `smart_cut` from package `cutr` :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/cutr")
library(cutr)

x <- -10:10
smart_cut(x, c(-2, 4, 6, 7), closed="right")

#  [1] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] [-10,-2] (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]   (-2,4]  
# [15] (-2,4]   (4,6]    (4,6]    7        (7,10]   (7,10]   (7,10]  
# Levels: [-10,-2] < (-2,4] < (4,6] < 7 < (7,10]
```

It has an `expand` argument set to `TRUE` by default, setting it to `FALSE` makes it work like `base::cut`.

[more on cutr and smart_cut](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/cutr)

Answer (score 0):

(My) `santoku` package automatically extends breaks if necessary:

```r
library(santoku)
x <- c(-10:10)

chop(x, c(-2, 4, 6, 7))

##  [1] [-10, -2) [-10, -2) [-10, -2) [-10, -2) [-10, -2) [-10, -2) [-10, -2) [-10, -2) [-2, 4)  
## [10] [-2, 4)   [-2, 4)   [-2, 4)   [-2, 4)   [-2, 4)   [4, 6)    [4, 6)    [6, 7)    [7, 10]  
## [19] [7, 10]   [7, 10]   [7, 10]  
## Levels: [-10, -2) [-2, 4) [4, 6) [6, 7) [7, 10]
```

You can control this behaviour using the `extend` argument to `chop()`.