# Cut and sort created data

Tags: r

I have this dataframe.

```
df <- read.table(text="
  amount      nr      date
  50          1       2017-01-01
  150         1       2017-01-03
  1500        2       2017-01-04
  1450        2       2017-01-04
  1250        2       2017-01-04
  950         1       2017-02-05
  120         3       2017-02-06
  300         3       2017-04-06
  ", header=TRUE)
```

I'd like to cut amount column by 100s and create new column from this. I used

```
df %>% mutate(
    bin_nr = cut(amount, breaks = seq(50, 1500, 100))
  )
```

But for some reason I get no just `(50,150]` but even `<NA>` (if amount is 1500 or 50) and `(1.15e+03,1.25e+03]`

So the question is 
1) how to have `(50,150]` even for amount 50 and 4 digit nrs `(1400,1500]` 
2) how to sort this newly created bin_nr column by value. I other words be able to sort values from smalest(largest) to largest(smalest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the `NA` values, specify the `breaks` with `-Inf` and `Inf` at the beginning/end of `seq` (in case there are values outside the range) and make sure the `dig.lab` is changed from default settings to not print with scientific notation

```
library(dplyr)
options(scipen = 999)
df %>%
   mutate(bin_nr = cut(amount, breaks = c(-Inf, 
        seq(50, 1500, 100), Inf), dig.lab = 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `include.lowest = T` option of the cut function and add the highest born at 1550 to have 1500. It is more or less a duplicate with :

[cut() - include lowest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245149/cut-include-lowest-values)